# deprecation warning when compiling: eta expansion of zero argument method

Tags: scala

When compiling this snippet, the scala compiler issues the following warning:

> Eta-expansion of zero-argument method values is deprecated. Did you
>   intend to write Main.this.porFiles5()? [warn]   timerFunc(porFiles5)

It occurs when I pass a function to another one for a simple timing. The timer function takes a parameterless function returning unit, at this line: `timerFunc(porFiles5)`. Is this warning necessary? What would be the idiomatic way to avoid it?

```
package example
import java.nio.file._
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import java.time._
import scala.collection.immutable._

object Main extends App {

  val dir = FileSystems.getDefault.getPath("C:\\tmp\\testExtract")

  def timerFunc (func:()=>Unit ) = {
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    timeNow()
    func()
    val finish = System.currentTimeMillis()
    timeNow()
    println((finish - start) / 1000.0 + " secs.")
    println("==================")
  }

  def porFiles5(): Unit = {
    val porFiles5 = Files.walk(dir).count()
    println(s"You have $porFiles5 por5 files.")
  }

  def timeNow(): Unit = {
    println(LocalTime.now)
  }

  timeNow()
  timerFunc(porFiles5)
  timeNow()

}
```

Comment: FWIW I would recommend changing `timerFunc` to just take a by name parameter e.g. `=> Unit`. It delays execution of your parameter as you need and nicely sidesteps the need to explicitly wrap something in a function.

Comment: @badcook thx. do you mean it like this (just to confirm): `timerFunc2(func: => Unit ): Unit { ... }`?

Comment: That's right, although perhaps `func` is no longer a good name :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`porFiles5` is *not* a function. It is a *method*, which is something completely different in Scala.

If you have a method, but you need a function, you can use η-expansion to lift the method into a function, like this:

```
someList.foreach(println _)
```

Scala will, in some cases, also perform η-expansion automatically, if it is absolutely clear from context what you mean, e.g.:

```
someList.foreach(println)
```

However, there is an ambiguity for parameterless methods, because Scala allows you to call parameterless methods without an argument list, i.e. a method defined with an *empty* parameter list can be called without any argument list at all:

```
def foo() = ???
foo // normally, you would have to say foo()
```

Now, in your case, there is an ambiguity: do you mean to *call* `porFiles5` or do you mean to η-expand it? At the moment, Scala arbitrarily disambiguates this situation and performs η-expansion, but in future versions, this will be an error, and you will have to explicitly perform η-expansion.

So, to get rid of the warning, simply use explicit η-expansion instead of implicit η-expansion:

```
timerFunc(porFiles5 _)
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Of course, I was a bit miffed when I couldn't pass in porfiles5() (my F# background coming through). So  I guess this would be a function:   `val porFiles6 = () => {
    val porFiles6 = Files.walk(dir).count()
    println(s"You have $porFiles6 por6 files.")
  }`.